# Spring Roo 2.0.0M2 sample script home page & tomcat issues

Tags: java, spring-roo

I'm testing the sample script at [Spring Roo 2.0.0M2 released](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/18/spring-roo-2-0-0m2-released). The script generates well, but when issueing mvn tomcat:run it breaks.
In the end there is no local website.

How to solve this to get the project running?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building foo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) > compile @ foo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ foo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) @ foo ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] incorrect classpath: D:\Tools\maven_repo\org\springframework\roo\org.springframework.roo.annotations\2.0.0.M2\org.springframework.roo.annotations-2.0.0.M2.pom
    <unknown source file>:<no line information>

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:test-compile (default) @ foo ---
[WARNING] No sources found skipping aspectJ compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ foo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 62 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ foo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ foo <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ foo ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.312 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-27T12:54:41+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/602M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Spring Roo 2.x generates Spring Boot applications. It includes some starters on your `pom.xml` file that provides you an embedded tomcat server. Also, your generated project includes the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` that allows you to run your application executing the following maven command:

`mvn clean compile spring-boot:run`

For more information about Spring Boot project read [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Hope this helps,

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks!  
**Compliments**: nice interface / gui. Looks great!
I forgot about Spring Boot. I did a project with 2.0.0.M1 and that version has not yet Spring Boot, so I'm accustomed to mvn tomcat:run